# How to remove std div in magento

Tags: magento

I was trying to remove the "std div" from my magento home page, but unable to find the same any suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

The div you are looking for is a page/html_wrapper block being added via the cms.xml layout file.

Here is the excerpt taken from app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cms.xml:

```
<cms_page translate="label">
        <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
                <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
```

So, there are a couple of ways to **remove the div** depending on how you develop your themes.

First option would be applicable if you use local.xml:

```
    <cms_page>
        <reference name="content">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <alias>cms.wrapper</alias>
            </action>
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
```

Second option would be applicable if you copy the base layout files over:

Copy cms.xml from `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cms.xml` to `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/cms.xml` and edit the first layout snippet from above to the following:

```
   <cms_page translate="label">
        <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml" />
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page" />
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
```

Comment: Heh, hate to be a nudge, but it seems worth pointing out an acadamic - as opposed to functionally meaningful - point: the middle option (for `local.xml`) will create a new `Mage_Cms_Block_Page` instance which overwrites the original one. Though I can't imagine a single visible effect for OOB CMS rendering, it may be relevant in edge cases.

Comment: You are right, though i'm not sure off the top of my head that there is a simple way of completely removing the outer wrapping div whilst keeping the original inner cms/page block intact?  Do you know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: So obvious now (ashamed I didn't spot that) :)

Comment: That's the danger with such an esoteric & undocumented gem as layout XML & block API.

Answer (score 3):

This code helped me to remove "std" div from a single cms page,
put it to "Layout Update XML" section:

```
<reference name="content">
<action method="unsetChild">
<alias>cms.wrapper</alias>
</action>
<block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
Drew asked a question which makes me realize that your questions was how to remove the div (not just remove the class of the div). Ideally it's like any other "move" operation in layout XML, which means unsetting a parent-child relationship (in this case the one between the `cms.wrapper` and `cms_page`) and setting the child to another block (`content`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
     <cms_page>
         <reference name="content">
             <action method="unsetChild">
                <alias>cms.wrapper</alias>
             </action>
             <action method="insert">
                <alias>cms_page</alias>
             </action>
         </reference>
    </cms_page>
</layout>
```

**My original response is below:**

Drew has a lot of good information in his answer. I'll just point out that the block API has some nuance that can make the layout XML very clean.

In your local.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
     <cms_page translate="label">
        <reference name="cms.wrapper">
            <action method="unsetElementClass" />
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
</layout>
```

Ref `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()` and `Varien_Object->__call()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you are finding :)

Put this xml code in Page -> Design -> Layout Update XML

```
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label"> 
<label>CMS Content Wrapper</label> 
<action method="setElementClass"><value>your_class_name</value></action> 
<block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/> 
</block>
```

Cheers!

Saran

Comment: this code puts a div instead of "std", but how to complete remove this div from DOM?